# Do all prime numbers satisfy $p \mid (p-1)! + 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $m > 1$, $m \mid (m-1)! + 1$, then we can get the conclusion that $m$ is a prime number. But if we have a prime number $p$, can I get $p \mid (p-1)! + 1$?
(I verify it when $p < 100000$, and there's no errors.)

In other words, can $m \mid (m-1)!+1$ generates all prime numbers?

Comment: Yes. That's what [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) says. It says $m$ is prime if and _only if_ $m\mid (m-1)!+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see this, note that $\mathbb{F}_p =\frac {\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb {Z}}$ is a field. In particular all elements apart from zero are units - that is to say, they are invertible. A unit and itsit'ss inverse multiply to 1.

All units appear in $ (p-1)! $. Thus we only need consider the self inverse elements (all others cancel each other mod $ p $.

What are they?

We are in a Field, so the equation $x^2 \equiv 1$ mod $p$ has at most 2 solutions. $1, -1$ are solutions, and so are the only ones.

$-1\equiv p-1$ mod $ p $ and so $$ (p-1)! \equiv 1 \text{ mod }p $$ i.e. $$ p | (p-1)! + 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Your question is exactly the Wilson's Theorem which states that,

$$p\textrm{ is a prime}\iff (p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$$

---

$$(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}\implies (p-1)!+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}\implies p\mid (p-1)!+1$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a natural number $n > 1$ is a prime number if and only if $(n-1)! \equiv-1\pmod n $ which is known as Wilson's theorem.